# How can I write C++ code to print variable values in python prompt with SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am new to SWIG and would like to wrap C++ classes and use it in python. As practice, I am writing a Vector class (similar to the one in STL). Now I want to print out the elements of a vector after entering the vector name in the python environment.

It is something like:

```
>>>v
1 2 3 4
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. > "print out the elements of a vector while entering their names"

Comment: Sorry. I should have said print out the elements of a vector after entering the vector name. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `%template` directive and the `std_vector.i` library in your .i file.

Reference: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_std_vector

### myModule.h file (C++ header file)

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> GetVectorInt();
```

### myModule.cpp file (C++ source file)

```
std::vector<int> GetVectorInt()
{
    std::vector<int> vOutput;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        vOutput.push_back(i);

    return vOutput;
}
```

### myModule.i file (SWIG interface file)

```
%module myModule
%{
#include "myModule.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"

%template(IntVector) std::vector<int>;

%include "myModule.h"
```

### Python output

```
>>> my_vector = myModule.GetVectorInt()
>>> my_vector
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```